# Do I need a view for each different action in a controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

Easy one, it's literally my first day with ASP.NET MVC

For example here, I'm adding a table to the lobby and then I would like to show the list of tables again, which I do in the index view.

Do I need to create an AddTable view with the same content as the index view?

Tried this but didn't work.

```
public class PokerController : Controller
{
    Lobby L;

    // GET: /Poker/
    public PokerController()
    {
        L = Lobby.Instance;
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(L.Tables);
    }

    public void AddTable()
    {
        L.Tables.Add(new Table(3));
        this.Index();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you guys, three great answers. Accepted the one which seemed more complete.

Voted the other two up though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need a view if the action is going to return a view specific to that action.  However, there are many `ActionResult` return values which any given action can return.  Files, raw text content, JSON, error responses, redirects, etc.

In this particular case it looks like you want to redirect the user back to the `Index` action.  This should do the trick:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View(L.Tables);
}

public ActionResult AddTable()
{
    L.Tables.Add(new Table(3));
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Poker");
}
```

If you don't want it to be a redirect, but instead want to explicitly return that view, this should work:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View(L.Tables);
}

public ActionResult AddTable()
{
    L.Tables.Add(new Table(3));
    return View("Index", L.Tables);
}
```

The main difference between the two, from the user's perspective, is that in the first case the URL they see will still be `"/Poker/Index"` whereas in the second case they will see `"/Poker/AddTable"`.  In most cases the former is preferred, as the latter can lead to odd behavior if you're not aware of it.

The main difference from the server-side code's perspective is that in the second case the actual `Index()` method will execute again, which may mean another trip to a database where one *technically* isn't necessary.  In most cases this isn't a problem, but if you have to really fine-tune your performance than it may be worth using the second approach in some cases.

Comment: could you give a hypothetical situation for 'odd'?  And how proper use can **avoid** 'leading' to odd.

Comment: @AndyzSmith: Any relative URLs (which includes default `BeginForm()` calls which don't explicitly specify an action) in the returned view would break, for example.  If anything depends on a referrer URL, that would change.  Primarily for me, it's really just a matter of intuitive URLs.  If one is looking at the current index of tables, one shouldn't be on a URL called `"AddTable"`.

Answer (score 2):

You can force any action to render the same view e.g.

```
public ActionResult AddTable()
{
    L.Tables.Add(new Table(3));
    return View("Index", L.Tables);   
}
```

The potential problem (it might not be for you) here is your URL would now look like `/AddTable`. It's generally a better idea to rely on proper data storage and use URL redirects e.g.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View(L.Tables);
}

public void AddTables()
{
    L.Tables.Add(new Tables(3));
    L.SaveToDB(); // just an example
    RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

So the table is added and the URL hasn't changed.

Answer (score 0):

you can make two views. one for showing the data list, another for adding data.
if you want to set the two actions in one page, you can using ajax.